# Remixjs - Redirect not loading all data when the creation request takes some time

Tags: javascript, remix.run

I have an action function that is populating the database with some info,the action sometimes takes 10 seconds or so in finishing the request that is like

```
const creatingData = await createdata();
```

Then I have a redirect that points to the created data

```
return redirect(`/myawesomepage/${creatingData.id}`);
```

The point is that when the page is loaded, the main content is not there, but if I reload the page all the content appears correctly.

I have tested with

```
throw redirect(`/myawesomepage/${creatingData.id}`);
```

But It has the same result. Im checking the documentation but I can not see how to wait for data or invalidating cache in order to force to load the page.

Comment: Can you show more of your action

Comment: nothing special ! gets data from a form and calls a function with await. Then redirects to the created page and some data is not there, reloads, and appears.

Comment: What do you mean by "some data is not there"? The useLoaderData hook contains only parts of the loader data? I think we need more insights here.

Comment: Let's say the database has 3 inputs, looks like is returning 2 the first time. Then when I reload returns the 3

Comment: Is your `createData` function actually returning a promise? Does the form submission take the whole 10s you expect, or is it faster? What is that function doing behind the scenes? Can you replicate the behavior outside of remix (like do createData and get the data immediately after) and see if all the data comes back? It could be that the system is "eventually consistent", meaning creating the data won't necessarily mean it's available to retrieve immediately afterward and takes time to populate.